# Memory Management in Caffe2

Tags: memory-management, caffe, caffe2

I am new to caffe2 and I wanted to know how does the caffe2 framework stores the models in the CPU or the GPU memory and how that is maintained. I have tried reading its github code but nothing concrete so far. Thanks for the help :) :)

Answer (score 0):

The models are stored using protobuf. The same as Caffe.

Check these out:

https://caffe2.ai/docs/tutorial-loading-pre-trained-models.html

https://caffe2.ai/docs/zoo.html

Comment: Thanks :) I actually was asking how is it loaded into the memory and used in the same ? :) Any help would be really really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The model is stored as a graph of operators. It is represented in storage as a protocol buffer and loaded into memory as a DAG.